# when I come back between screens my data is lost in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The data I selected on the 1st screen is gone when I come back to the 1st screen from the 2nd screen. I want this data to still show up. How can I do that. There was a way to do this, but I don't remember exactly, so I have to ask.

I'm doing this in Kotlin by the way.

**for example**

1- I enter the values ​​on the first screen

2- I switch to the second screen with the help of a button

3- I go back to the first screen with the help of a button from the second

screen and the values ​​I entered are gone.

**pictures**

### my first screen

[image]

### my second screen

[image]

**and when I come back**

[image]

Comment: A better approach would be using ViewModel to save the current state of your activity and retrieve that value from ViewModel again when you come back.

Comment: Are you using `NavigationComponent`? I supposed that you did. The default behavior of `NavigationComponent` is it replaces the previous fragment when you navigate to another fragment. That will destroy the previous fragment's view but not the fragment itself. When you navigate back, said view is being re-create hence its state is reset. To save the view's state, you can use the fragment itself, the `ViewModel`, saved instance state, or event using data persistent depending on your use cases. To understand this behavior you can read more about fragment's lifecycle and activity's lifecycle.

Comment: You can also read more about saving the UI states in the Android documentation section [Save UI states.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Shared preference simply

1-Primitive data types approach

Store in SharedPreference(your first activity) :

```
val sharedPreference=getSharedPreferences("preference file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()

        
        sharedPreference.putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true)
        sharedPreference.putInt("id",1)
        sharedPreference.putString("name","Alex")
        sharedPreference.apply()
```

Now we retrieve it from SharedPreference

You can also retrieve it in your first activity if you already saved the data in the first run, So we check if the shared is null or not

```
    val sharedPreference=getSharedPreferences("preference file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()

      if(sharedPreference!= null){
        val name = sharedPreference.getString("name", "")
        val id = sharedPreference.getInt("id", 0)
        val isLoggedIn = sharedPreference.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false)
    }
```

and this is for clearing the data of the shared preference, But the shared preferences's file won't be deleted (in activity context):

```
this.getSharedPreferences("preference file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply();
```

2- Your object-type approach

We will be using the Gson library to do so, Which is going to convert your POJO to a string and then convert the string to JSON,And When we want to receive the object the algorithm will reversed :

Install GSON dependency in gradle for the converting:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
```

Store in Gson SharedPreference :

```
val sharedPreference=
                getSharedPreferences(
                    "preference file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE
                ).edit()

            val customer= Customer() // your object what ever it is
             

            val gsonCustomer = Gson()
            val customerJson= gsonCustomer.toJson(customer)
            sharedPreference.putString("customer object", customerJson)
            sharedPreference.apply()
```

Retrieve from  Gson SharedPreference:

```
val sharedPreference=
            getSharedPreferences(
                "preference file", MODE_PRIVATE
            )
        val gson = Gson()
        if (sharedPreference!= null)
        {
            val customerJson: String = sharedPreference.getString("customer object", "")!!
            customer= gson.fromJson(customerJson, Customer::class.java)
        }
```

Clear Shared Preference data same as previous approach (in activity context) :

```
 this.getSharedPreferences("preference file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply();
```